# Maven project deployment in jboss

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have two maven projects Hibernate and ServerService, ServerService has a dependency in pom.xml to Hibernate Project; now I want to deploy ServerService.war file in JBoss, but get an error Error `org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner`.

```xml
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>Hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>Hibernate</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: @peeskillet JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."JavaProjectServiceServer.war#MyPersistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."JavaProjectServiceServer.war#MyPersist
enceUnit": Failed to start service

Comment: 21:16:16,812 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps
that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"JavaProjectServiceServer.war#MyPersistenceUnit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"JavaProjectSer
viceServer.war#MyPersistenceUnit\": Failed to start service"}}}}